# How to display html output in the same page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing an app to grab pictures from social networks.
How can I add make sure that when the user clicks the links, the output (which consists of the grabbed pictures) is displayed in the same page?

I wrote separate php files for each of them, and they all go to separate pages. I want to put them on the same page. How can I run the php files in the same page?

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv">View</a>
<br /> 
<div id="slidingDiv"> 
    <a href="/Gravatar/gravindex.php">Gravatar</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: keep them in different divs, and just show the div you want to without hiding the exisiting ones

Comment: try `$.ajax(), $.get(), .load()` from jquery, whichever suits you. or you can use `<?php incude() ?>, includeOnce, requireOnce etc.`

Comment: @Deepanshu, i'm using a jquery plugin which has the following code in the html page.
<a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv">View</a><br />
    <div id="slidingDiv">
        <a href="/Gravatar/gravindex.php">Gravatar</a>
    </div>

Where should my gravatar php be linked?

Comment: post your jquery code you are using

Answer (score 1):

That depeneds on the link not to php. if you use `target="_self"` it will be open in the same page

Comment: okay, so if i use target="_self" in <a> tag then will the link open in the same page? without a refresh.

Comment: It will be opened in the same page but you need a refresh. otherwise you have to use jquery and ajax if you want no refresh at all

Comment: also you don't put it, by default "_self" will be used.